# Repetitive 1-9 pow last digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory, power-series, totient-function

So i'm pretty bad at math, but trying to solve this programming problem where there are an N amount of power values in the range of 1-9 and the last number has to be found. I have checked multiple threads here and also https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-the-last-digit-of-a-power/ and Euler Totient function. However, the truth is that i'm kinda stupid, i can do some solid head calculations up to 5 digit numbers squared. But when it comes to advanced math.. i'm way behind. So could possibly anyone out there explain to me how this works?

To be more specific:
lets take $9^{4^{2^{3^5}}}$

What is `k` when you use modulus, and how is it used?

What is ?

Why do you get a negative number when using modulus? Shouldn't it leave a remainder instead?

TLDR; Can someone explain how to get last digit of $9^{4^{2^{3^5}}}$ for person that is pretty bad at math?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting math on this site.

Comment: For $\phi$, Google "Euler totient."

Comment: Please add the tag "elementary-number-theory". Else it will get much less exposure.

Comment: thank you @BillDubuque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear to me what you mean by
"problem where there are an N amount of power values in the range of 1-9 and the
last number has to be found". Is this to say you're dealing with a power tower
of integers in the range 1-9?

In any case, to find the last digit of $9^{4^{2^{3^5}}}$, we want to "reduce it
mod $10$". First, some notation.
\begin{equation*}
 a \equiv b \pmod{10}
\end{equation*}
means that "$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo $10$". This means that they differ by
a multiple of $10$, or equivalently, they leave the same remainder when divided
by $10$. Hopefully you agree that if some integer
\begin{equation*}
n \equiv 3 \pmod{10}
\end{equation*}
then the last digit of $n$ must be $3$.

Now, we also have that if $a \equiv b \pmod{10}$ and $c \equiv d \pmod{10}$,
then $ac \equiv bd \pmod{10}$. Maybe this is obvious to you already, if not, you
can prove it from the "differ by a multiple of $10$" definition. Using this,
any power of $9$ is congruent to $-1$ raised to that same exponent. So
\begin{equation*}
 9^{4^{2^{3^5}}} \equiv (-1)^{4^{2^{3^5}}} \pmod{10}
\end{equation*}
But the value of $(-1)^{4^{2^{3^5}}}$ just depends on whether
$4^{2^{3^5}}$ is even or odd. Since this is some power of $4$, which is even,
it is clearly even (since it is not $4^0$), so $(-1)^{4^{2^{3^5}}} = 1$, so the
last digit of $9^{4^{2^{3^5}}}$ is $1$.

An alternative approach would just be to look at powers of $9$ mod $10$, and
notice that they are congruent to $1$, $9$, $1$, $9$, ... and take it from
there.

To generalise this approach for some kind of program requires looking at the
periodicity of the powers of the base modulo $10$, and then recursing into the
power tower to reduce the subtower modulo the period of the powers of the base.
(Particularly, not all numbers are as nice as $9$, which only has period $2$)

**Proof** of $a \equiv b \pmod{10}$ and
$c \equiv d \pmod{10} \implies ac \equiv bd \pmod{10}$.

Have $a = b + 10n$, $c = d + 10m$ for some $n, m \in \mathbb Z$ by definition..
Then
\begin{align*}
 ac
  &= (b + 10n)(d + 10n) \\
  &= bd + 10(n + m + 10nm) \\
  &\equiv bd \pmod{10} \quad \text{by definition}
\end{align*}

**Proof** of $a \equiv b \pmod{10} \implies a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{10}$:

The base case $n = 0$ is trivially true. Then
\begin{align*}
 a^{n + 1}
  &\equiv a \cdot a^n \\
  &\equiv b \cdot a^n \quad \text{by assumption} \\
  &\equiv b \cdot b^n \quad \text{by inductive hypothesis} \\
  &\equiv b^{n + 1}
\end{align*}

Comment: You lost me But the value of $(-1)^{4^{2^{3^5}}}$ just depends on whether $4^{2^{3^5}}$ is even or odd. Since this is some power of $4$, which is even, it is clearly even (since it is not $4^0$), so $(-1)^{4^{2^{3^5}}} = 1$, so the last digit of $9^{4^{2^{3^5}}}$ is $1$. here... Also, how to make this more generic? beginning with 9 was just an example, lets say you start with 8 or 4, (i guess 5 always end with 5...)

Comment: $-1$ raised to any odd power is $-1$, and raised to any even power is $1$, so we only need to know whether or not the bit on top is even or odd. As for generic, that's what the last paragraph was trying to get at. If the base is $8$, you can calculate that the powers of $8$ go $1$, $8$, $4$, $6$, $2$, $8$ and repeat from there. Then you just need to know if the power you're raising it to is congruent to 0, 1, 2, or 3 mod 4.

Comment: Right, so how do i know if a number $8^{9^{9^9}}$ which result in a 369 million digit power off is congruent to 0,1,2 or 4? Edit: Sorry, as i mentioned above, i'm not that skilled when it comes to math

Comment: @Vollan, by looking at the powers of $8$ mod $4$! And those happen to all be $0$, so $8^{9^{9^9}} \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. Basically you just apply the whole procedure again, but this time we're looking for the last digit in base 4. This is what I meant by recursing. Please don't feel the need to apologise, lord knows there's enough maths I don't understand : )

Comment: @Vollan or maybe you meant what $9^{9^9}$ would be mod $4$, which is $1$, since $9 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$

Comment: I mean  kinda any number, let's take 7.. 7 mod 4 is 3, 7^2 is 49 and last digit is 9. So how do i go here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102079/discussion-between-izaak-van-dongen-and-vollan).